# Consulta de ingreso en MYSQLI con PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

estoy haciendo un ingreso para una página php, pero quiero que en el formulario de ingreso solo de acceso al usuario que se identifique con nombre de **usuario**: admin y **clave**: 12345, ya todo está registrado en base de datos.

```
$resultados = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM $tabla_db2 WHERE user='$user' AND pass='$pass'");
while($consulta = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados)) {
   $_SESSION['sesion_exito'] = 1;//Inicio Sesion :D
}
```

Con este código si me da ingreso, para cualquier usuario que esté en la base de datos pero si quiero hacerlo más específico para darle acceso sólo a un administrador, no me da el permiso.

```
$resultados = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM $tabla_db2 WHERE user='admin' AND pass='12345'");
while($consulta = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados)) {
   $_SESSION['sesion_exito'] = 1;//Inicio Sesion :D
}
```

Comment: Hola, si quieres dar acceso solo a administradores te recomiendo crear una columna "admin" en tu tabla de usuarios para guardar si el usuario tiene permisos de administrador, y luego desde PHP hacer la comprobación para darle acceso o no.

Comment: No veo las variables $user, $pass ni $tabla_db2, ¿Cómo las estás recuperando? Aparte tienes un hueco de seguridad enorme. Espero que sea un proyecto de tu escuela, si no si te falta una buena consultoría.

Comment: $user = $_POST['user'];
      $pass = $_POST['pass'];

Comment: $user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

estas son las variables las tengo mas arriba realmente solo puse el codigo que recupera datos, cual  es hueco de seguridad ?
sii es de la escuela jeje, tengo otro archivo de abrir la conexión donde tengo el usuario y la clave para acceder a la base de datos

Comment: El hueco de seguridad que te indican se llama **INYECCIÓN SQL** y es un fallo de seguridad grave: http://php.net/manual/es/security.database.sql-injection.php